# printing text on image in javascript error

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

i am creating an html section with javascript to print text on image. When the user enters the text in input box, the text will be printed on image and user can download that image. I have tried the following code for achieving this

```js
var text_title = "Heading";
  var text_title1 = "Heading";
  var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
  imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
  var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var img = new Image();
  img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

  window.addEventListener('load', DrawPlaceholder)

  function DrawPlaceholder() {
    img.onload = function() {
      DrawOverlay(img);
      DrawText();
      DynamicText(img)
    };
    img.src = 'https://unsplash.it/400/400/?random';

  }

  function DrawOverlay(img) {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(30, 144, 255, 0.4)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }

  function DrawText() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
    ctx.font = "50px 'Montserrat'";
    ctx.fillText(text_title, 50, 50);
    ctx.fillText(text_title1, 150, 150);
  }

  function DynamicText(img) {
    document.getElementById('name').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      DrawOverlay(img);
      DrawText();
      text_title = this.value;
      ctx.fillText(text_title, 50, 50);
    });

    document.getElementById('name1').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      DrawOverlay(img);
      DrawText();
      text_title = this.value;
      ctx.fillText(text_title1, 150, 150);
    });


  }

  function handleImage(e) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var img = "";
    var src = "";
    reader.onload = function(event) {
      img = new Image();
      img.onload = function() {
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      }
      img.src = event.target.result;
      src = event.target.result;
      canvas.classList.add("show");
      DrawOverlay(img);
      DrawText();
      DynamicText(img);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);

  }

  function convertToImage() {
    window.open(canvas.toDataURL('png'));
  }
  document.getElementById('download').onclick = function download() {
    convertToImage();
  }
```

```css
.page-wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2em auto;
  }
  
  .controls {
    &__input {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background: none;
      border: none;
      font-size: 1em;
      padding-bottom: .5em;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
      text-align: center;
      outline: none;
      color: #fff;
    }
    &__btn {
      background: dodgerblue;
      color: #fff;
      border: none;
      font-size: 1em;
    }
    &__label {
      display: block;
      font-size: .8em;
      padding-top: .3em;
      margin-bottom: 2em;
    }
  }
  
  canvas {
    background-color: #eee;
    // opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .3s;
    &.show {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  
  .canvas-wrap {
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  #canvasID {
    z-index: 9999;
  }
```

```html
<div class="page-wrap">
  <div class="controls">
    <input class="controls__input" type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader" />
    <label class="controls__label" for="name">First, choose an image.</label>

    <input class="controls__input" id="name" type="text" value="" />
    <label class="controls__label" for="name">Overlay Text</label>

    <input class="controls__input" id="name1" type="text" value="" />
    <label class="controls__label" for="name1"> Text</label>
  </div>
  <div id="canvas-wrap">
    <canvas style="display:block" id="imageCanvas" width=400px height=400px>
        <canvas id="canvasID"></canvas>
    </canvas>
  </div>

</div>
```

now when the user inputs text in the first box, its working fine, the text is being printed. But the second box is not working. Its not applying the text in second input box to image. Somebody please tell me what i am doing wrong. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your code; everything else is the same

```
document.getElementById('name1').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      DrawOverlay(img);
      DrawText();
      // text_title = this.value; incorrect variable
      text_title1 = this.value;
      ctx.fillText(text_title1, 150, 150);
    });
```

```html
<style type="text/css">
  .page-wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2em auto;
  }
  
  .controls {
    &__input {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background: none;
      border: none;
      font-size: 1em;
      padding-bottom: .5em;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
      text-align: center;
      outline: none;
      color: #fff;
    }
    &__btn {
      background: dodgerblue;
      color: #fff;
      border: none;
      font-size: 1em;
    }
    &__label {
      display: block;
      font-size: .8em;
      padding-top: .3em;
      margin-bottom: 2em;
    }
  }
  
  canvas {
    background-color: #eee;
    // opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .3s;
    &.show {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  
  .canvas-wrap {
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  #canvasID {
    z-index: 9999;
  }
</style>



<div class="page-wrap">
  <div class="controls">
    <input class="controls__input" type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader" />
    <label class="controls__label" for="name">First, choose an image.</label>

    <input class="controls__input" id="name" type="text" value="" />
    <label class="controls__label" for="name">Overlay Text</label>

    <input class="controls__input" id="name1" type="text" value="" />
    <label class="controls__label" for="name1"> Text</label>
  </div>
  <div id="canvas-wrap">
    <canvas style="display:block" id="imageCanvas" width=400px height=400px>
        <canvas id="canvasID"></canvas>
    </canvas>
  </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var text_title = "Heading";
  var text_title1 = "Heading";
  var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
  imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
  var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var img = new Image();
  img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

  window.addEventListener('load', DrawPlaceholder)

  function DrawPlaceholder() {
    img.onload = function() {
      DrawOverlay(img);
      DrawText();
      DynamicText(img)
    };
    img.src = 'https://unsplash.it/400/400/?random';

  }

  function DrawOverlay(img) {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(30, 144, 255, 0.4)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }

  function DrawText() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
    ctx.font = "50px 'Montserrat'";
    ctx.fillText(text_title, 50, 50);
    ctx.fillText(text_title1, 150, 150);
  }

  function DynamicText(img) {
    document.getElementById('name').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      DrawOverlay(img);
      DrawText();
      text_title = this.value;
      ctx.fillText(text_title, 50, 50);
    });

    document.getElementById('name1').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      DrawOverlay(img);
      DrawText();
      text_title1 = this.value;
      ctx.fillText(text_title1, 150, 150);
    });


  }

  function handleImage(e) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var img = "";
    var src = "";
    reader.onload = function(event) {
      img = new Image();
      img.onload = function() {
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      }
      img.src = event.target.result;
      src = event.target.result;
      canvas.classList.add("show");
      DrawOverlay(img);
      DrawText();
      DynamicText(img);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);

  }

  function convertToImage() {
    window.open(canvas.toDataURL('png'));
  }
  document.getElementById('download').onclick = function download() {
    convertToImage();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: happy to help! :D